# 12.04 64bit detects 7.7 GB Of RAM Out Of 8 GB

Tags: 12.04, hardware, ram

I've `Dell Inspiron N5110` with `8 GB of RAM`, I installed Ubuntu 12.04 64-Bit.

The problem is that all things are working fine but Ubuntu detects only 7.7 GB of RAM, I've checked & noticed that I've 4 GB of Kingston & 4 GB of Samsung RAM.

Now I've installed Windows to check if it is RAM fault or what, Windows 7 is showing 8 GB of RAM.

Dedicated graphics yes
Video card NVIDIA GeForce GT 525M (DirectX11, SM 5.0, PureVideoHD)
Video card memory 1 024 MB

http://ark.intel.com/products/53469

Intel® Core™ i7-2670QM Processor
(6M Cache, up to 3.10 GHz)

Processor Graphics  Intel® HD Graphics 3000

### Updated

**there is no option in bios to set graphic card ram or to set which graphic card to use ... i have checked 7 to 8 time ...**

Comment: Check /var/log/kern.log or `dmesg` and look for the section listing the bios e820 map and add that to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> so the problem is that all things are working fine but Ubuntu detects only 7.7 GB of ram

Your laptop (Dell N5110) uses Intel integrated graphics (HD Graphics 2000), and this uses some amount of your RAM as "Graphics Memory". Compare to a dedicated graphics/video card which has its own onboard RAM. Even if your laptop has a dedicated ATI/NVidia card, the laptop is usually set by default to automatically "switch" between the two (Nvidia calls this *Optimus*), and that means that the integrated Intel graphics will reserve memory even if you aren't using them.

Windows includes the reserved video RAM in its count, while Ubuntu doesn't. You can't use this reserved RAM in either OS, in any case.

Your BIOS should let you set a specific value for the amount to be reserved, instead of automatic -- I recommend you pick at least 128MB. Then Ubuntu will show the remainder (8064 MB) as available and usable. Alternately, if you wish to only use the discrete (Nvidia/ATI) card, you can also select that as an option in the BIOS, disabling Intel graphics completely, which should give you access to *all* of your RAM (warning: this may decrease battery life).

Comment: i have 1 gb of nvidia integrated graphic card

Comment: You need to disable `Optimus` (switching) then, and set your BIOS to use only "discrete" (i.e., Nvidia only).

Comment: let me chk in bios & let you know

Comment: i have checked in the bios there is no option for graphic ...

Comment: How about `share memory`, `vram`, or something along those lines? It is probably under advanced settings somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

It no problem after all you are having 7.7GB Ram .. Their should not Be any performance issue.Your ram is shared with integrated graphics memory of your Processor, So don't take it seriously your PC is Fine.