# Why is the total RAM for my HP dm1 less than the actual it should be?

Tags: 12.04, ati, ram, amd-processor

First time poster, so I apologize right off the bat if I'm doing something wrong (following Murphy's Law, I probably am).

Anyway, I was wondering why the 2GB RAM I have installed in my HP Pavilion dm1 (E-450 variant) is only being recognized as 1.6GB. Is it because I configured something wrong (or failed to configure something)?

One guess I have as to where the remaining 400MB is going is the video card, which (based on Ubuntu Tweak) uses 380+MB of memory.

I know that I can make use of the full 2GB; Windows 7 says as much. I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One guess I have as to where the remaining 400MB is going is the video card, which (based on Ubuntu Tweak) uses 380+MB of memory.

That is the correct answer, the Video card has the remainder reserved, hence Ubuntu is not showing it as available to the rest of the system.

Comment: Are you sure about the 1000KB/1000MB measurement? I'm pretty sure that this applies to hard disks and *not* to memory.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I'm not absolutely sure, Web-E edited the answer to include it, I edited his addition for easier readability.  If you do the math it comes out to 1.628GB at 1024kb & 1.582GB at 1000kb....I will edit the answer to remove this info as I'm not sure....that's what I get for accepting the edit just before going to bed..

Comment: @JoachimSauer According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte) it is 1024kb when applied to RAM thank you for the correction.

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer, @TrailRider. I had a bad feeling that this was the case. Doesn't the video card have its own dedicated RAM, though? And if so, is there anything I can do in the ay of configuring my laptop to use that RAM for the video instead of hogging the general purpose one?

Comment: I found [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/137596/78515) answer to a somewhat similar question, which actually also answers my follow-up question just now. It seems even though Windows reports that extra 380+MB and Ubuntu doesn't, the behavior is still the same. Sorry I didn't try that much harder to look for an answer to my question.